# Apache Pig: REGEX_EXTRACT second dir name from a string containing a path

Tags: apache-pig

Good afternoon,

After extracting data from a NameNode log and filtering it, I get an output like:

```
DUMP USERS_AND_DIRS;

(UserName,/user/UserName/Dir1,/user/UserName/Dir2)
(UserName2,/user/UserName2/Dir1,/user/UserName2/Dir2)
(UserName,/hdfs/data/Dir1,/hdfs/data/Dir2)
(UserName,/user/UserName/Dir1,/user/UserName2/Dir2)
```

AS (User, Source, Destination)

Now I want to filter by users using directories that are not their own.
I have :

```
ONLY_IN_USER_DIR = FILTER USERS_AND_DIRS BY (Source MATCHES '/user/(.*)') OR (Destination MATCHES '/user/(.*)');
```

Which works fine. But this does't work :

```
USING_DIR_OF_OTHER_USER = FILTER ONLY_IN_USER_DIR BY NOT(Source MATCHES '/user/$User/(.*)') OR NOT (Destination MATCHES '/user/$User/(.*)');
```

Given the input, I'd like to only get :

```
(UserName,/user/UserName/Dir1,/user/UserName2/Dir2)
```

Which are users accessing files in directories other than their own, as a source or destination. I tried different things, yet I can't find how to do this ?

---

**Edit**: I think I can do something like

```
DIR_OF_OTHER_USER = FILTER ONLY_IN_USER_DIR BY User != REGEX_EXTRACT(Source,'/(.*)/',2) OR User != REGEX_EXTRACT(Destination,'/(.*)/',2);
```

But when Source is "/user/UserDir/Dir1/Dir2", `REGEX_EXTRACT(Source,'/(.*)/',1)` returns `(user)` and `REGEX_EXTRACT(Source,'/(.*)/',2)` returns nothing.

So I guess my question is now : how can I extract the second directory from a string containing a path ? From "/user/UserDir/Dir1/Dir2" and I would like to extract "UserDir"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I extract the second directory from a string containing a path ? From "/user/UserDir/Dir1/Dir2" and I would like to extract "UserDir"

How about

```
STRSPLIT(Source,'/').$2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it :

```
DIR_OF_OTHER_USER = FILTER ONLY_IN_USER_DIR BY (
                        User != REGEX_EXTRACT(Source, '^\\/([^\\/]*)\\/([^\\/]*)', 2) AND REGEX_EXTRACT(Source, '^\\/([^\\/]*)\\/([^\\/]*)', 1) == 'user'
                        ) OR (
                        User != REGEX_EXTRACT(Destination, '^\\/([^\\/]*)\\/([^\\/]*)', 2) AND REGEX_EXTRACT(Source, '^\\/([^\\/]*)\\/([^\\/]*)', 1) == 'user'
                        );
```

This gets all files used by a user, which is in a /user/* directory but not in the user's directory /user/UserName/ . Although there might be a simpler answer.